# How to execute a .command file using Terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, terminal, command

Once I navigate to a certain directory that has a .command file in it, how do I execute that file using Terminal?

Comment: It depends on the contents of that file. What’s the output of the `file` command when run against that file, e.g. `file /somedir/somefile.command`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to execute it as if it was double-clicked in the Finder, you can use `open foo.command`. This will spawn a new Terminal window. If you want to execute it "inline", as it were, you can just use `./foo.command`, as .command files must have the exec bit set in order to function.